# how to accept multi thread's connection request in FD_ACCEPT?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, winapi, chat

If I have n Client connect the Server,how to accept it in FD_ACCEPT and how to receive it in FD_READ and how to send it in FD_WRITE and not use like this form

e.p.

```
    while(1){
        ClientSocket=accept(ListenSocket,0,0);
        if(ClientSocket!=INVALID_SOCKET)
            _beginthreadex();
    }
```

how to achieve it in this form

```
case WM_SERVER_SOCKET:
    wEvent = WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam);//LOWORD
    switch (wEvent) {
    case FD_ACCEPT:
        ClientSocket=accept(ListenSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
        break;
    case FD_READ:

        break;
    case FD_WRITE:

        break;
    case FD_CLOSE:

        break;
    }
    break;
```

or this form just can handle one Client connection?
is it necessary do it in this form?
I want use it for a simple chat application

Comment: you means i shouldn't do it in this form? I previously thought it will needn't create more thread and hope it will have some method to auto handle multi client message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WSAAsyncSelect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540.aspx) is what you are looking for, eg:

```
WNDCLASS cls = {0};
cls.lpfnWndProc = &SocketWndProc;
cls.hInstance = ...;
cls.lpszClassName = TEXT("MySocketWnd");

RegisterClass(&cls);

HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, cls.lpszClassName, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, nullptr, cls.hInstance, nullptr);

SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(...);
bind(ListenSocket, ...);
listen(ListenSocket, ...);

WSAAsyncSelect(ListenSocket, hWnd, WM_SERVER_SOCKET, FD_ACCEPT | FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CLOSE);

MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);       
}

closesocket(ListenSocket);
DestroyWindow(hWnd);
```

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SocketWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg != WM_SERVER_SOCKET)
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    SOCKET sckt = (SOCKET) wParam;
    WORD wEvent = WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam);
    WORD wError = WSAGETSELECTERROR(lParam);

    if (wError != 0)
    {
        // wEvent on sckt failed, do something ...
        return 0;
    }

    switch (wEvent)
    {
        case FD_ACCEPT:
        {
            // sckt has a pending client...
            SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(sckt,...);
            // do something with new client (add it to a tracking list, etc) ...
            break;
        }

        case FD_READ:
        {
            // sckt has pending data...
            int numBytes = recv(sckt, ...);
            // process data as needed...
            break;
        }

        case FD_WRITE:
        {
            // sckt can receive data, send any pending data ...
            break;
        }

        case FD_CLOSE:
        {
            // sckt has disconnected, do something (remove it from list, etc)...
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: int numBytes = recv(sckt, ...); - -,the sckt will is the ClientSocket? and how to send to a Client,save the ClientSocket then SendMessage()? send all is  similar?

Comment: In the `FD_ACCEPT` event, the provided socket will be the listening socket.  In all of the other events, the provided socket will be one of the accepted client sockets, yes.